# Which face detection method suitable for detecting faces of people at a long distance?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

I have checked five different methods for face detection.
     1. Haar cascade 
     2. Dlib HOG 
     3. Python face_recognition module 
     4. DLib_CNN 
     5. OpenCV CNN 
All these methods have some advantages and disadvantages and i found out that openCV_CNN works better out of these five algorithm. But for my application i need to detect faces from people on far distance and for this purpose even OpenCV_CNN is not working well (it detects faces of people closer to camera and not the people on far distance). Is there any other algorithm which detects faces of people on far distance?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to do instance segmentation in order to get all the classes in the environment including distant objects. 
Once you get all the classes, you can draw a bounding box around the required far off face class, upsample it and send it to your face detection NN. suppose your image is of 54x54x3, it will be upsampled to 224x224x3 and sent to your trained NN.

Answer (score 0):

**Face Detection State-of-the-art practical considerations**

Face Detection is often the first stage of a Computer Vision pipeline. Thus, it is important for the algorithm to perform in real time. So, it is important to know the [**comparison between various face detection algorithms and their pros and cons to use the right algorithm for your application**](https://learnopencv.com/what-is-face-detection-the-ultimate-guide/). There are many algorithms that have been developed over the years as shown below.
[image]

Our recent favorite is **YuNet** because of its **balance between speed and accuracy**. Apart from that, **RetinaFace is also very accurate but it is a larger model and is a little slow**. We have compared the [**top 9 algorithms for Face Detection**](https://learnopencv.com/what-is-face-detection-the-ultimate-guide/) on some of the features that we should keep in mind while choosing a Face Detection algorithm:

**Speed**
[image]

**Accuracy**
[image]

**Size of face**
[image]

**Robustness to occlusion**
[image]

**Robustness to Lighting variation**
[image]

Robustness to Orientation or Pose
[image]

You can check out the [Face Detection ultimate guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Di50FIoq8w) that gives a brief overview of the popular face detection algorithms.